# Amazon IR emitter and a PI 2

Tags: pi-2

I want to make an IR blaster with my PI 2 to turn appliances off at certain times of the day.  The HVAC at 11pm so it doesn't stay on all night for example.  My question really is; if I get one of these

[IR Emitter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001DF7EC8)

can i link it to my PI GPIO and have it send IR signals? (I expect to have to use some other bits too and will probably need to chop the plug off).

This seems like a simple way to get an IR module a decent distance from my PI :)

Comment: I assume you were linking to the emitter in question, but your link is broken. You will probably have an easier time with just an IR Led. You will need a way to capture/clone the existing code and frequency used by the remote. An Arduino and IR sensor will work (a google search will turn up several tutorials). Alternatively this software (and the IR learner and receiver) which runs on the Pi http://www.analysir.com/blog/get-analysir/  makes this very simple and provides several additional features.

Comment: I see it has a jack at the end, so I suppose making it transmit certain signal (or signal at all) isn't trivial task. I would recommend solution Steve gave you above. It would be trivial then, when connected to GPIO (I don't know about voltages IR diode takes, but that's not a difficult problem) as GPIO library is easy to use and reliable.
And @SteveRobillard, you could paste your comment into an answer, as it actually answers the question ;)

Answer (score 2):

The linked item seems to need a "repeater kit" to work.  It seems to be an IR extender rather than an IR blaster.

You can make your own IR blaster quite inexpensively, especially if you have some resistors and a transistor.

Here is an IR blaster I made using an IR LED salvaged from a remote control I was throwing away.

[image: IR blaster]

My blaster is driven by a Pi gpio.  It is powered from 5V and the IR LED is switched on and off via a gpio connected to the base of the transistor.

I've used it to send fairly standard IR remote commands which are typically quite short,  of the order of 40 bits of information.

You should note that the IR signal is built on top of a modulated carrier in the region of 38 kHz.  You typically send a bit by a burst of carrier (say 400 µs) followed by a gap whose length determines whether the bit is a zero or a 1.

Air conditioning units tend to have much longer commands, being perhaps several 100s of bits long.  I haven't tried to send such commands (I don't have such a device) but in principle it should be possible.

Of course there are the commercial solutions such as the one pointed to by Steve.